# Edge generation in networkx

Tags: python, graph, networkx, bipartite

I would like to ask a question about bipartite graph generation over Networkx. I'm trying to find the way, how to generate the nodes for bipartite graph. But I wasn't very successful.

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3

import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#max_diameter_cnt = 4
#max_nodes_cnt = 7
#max_degree_cnt = 2

G = nx.Graph()
# data example
G.add_edges_from([('0', '1'), ('0', '2'), ('1', '3'),
                  ('3', '5'), ('2', '4'), ('4', '6'),
                  ('5', '6')])

print(nx.diameter(G))

nx.draw(G, with_labels=True)
plt.show()
```

Currently everything is hardcoded. But I would like generate it base on parameters.

1. Diameter has to be set to "4". (Max distance between nodes.)
2. For degree **2**, is Moore bound calculated to **7**. But I wanted to change it like <2,3,4>. Moore bound is calculated as <7,22,53>.
3. How to generate the node list, especially the neighbors edges then?

Many thanks for any support.

Andy

Comment: Is there any requirement for randomness, or is any working solution that produces a graph with the desired characteristics acceptable?  One might envision starting with one of the following three options for [generators in the bipartite section](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/bipartite.html#module-networkx.algorithms.bipartite.generators) of the networkx docs and modifying the random output in a methodical way or perhaps just brute-forcing the requirements: `complete_bipartite_graph()`, `random_graph()`, or `gnmk_random_graph()`.

Comment: Output could be randomness. It should just accept only those criteria:
- bipartite set of A/B (not complete one)
 - A partition should have <2,3,4> number of nodes
 - B partition should have 2*<2,3,4> number of nodes
- max distance between A and B node is 4

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, the following should work. This solution uses [`gnmk_random_graph()`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.bipartite.generators.gnmk_random_graph.html#networkx-algorithms-bipartite-generators-gnmk-random-graph), but you could certainly use [`random_graph()`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.bipartite.generators.random_graph.html#networkx-algorithms-bipartite-generators-random-graph) instead.  The output is generated by random processes, but whether the solutions are randomly distributed depends on how you define the set of graphs to sample.

```
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx
from networkx.algorithms.bipartite.generators import gnmk_random_graph

nodes_in_A = 3  # Primary parameter to change

nodes_in_B = 2 * nodes_in_A
diam = 4
max_attempts = 1000

for attempt in range(max_attempts):
    num_edges = np.random.randint(nodes_in_B, nodes_in_A * nodes_in_B)
    G = gnmk_random_graph(nodes_in_A, nodes_in_B, num_edges)
    if not nx.is_connected(G):
        pass
    elif nx.diameter(G) == diam:
        node_color = [d['bipartite'] for n, d in G.nodes(data=True)]
        nx.draw(G, with_labels=True, node_color=node_color, cmap='bwr')
        break
    if attempt == max_attempts - 1:
        print('Graph generation failed with current parameters.')
```

which gives, for example:

[image: diameter_4_bipartite_graph]

Comment: Thanks @Frodnar for this solution. It's very close, what I've expected. There is only one part missing. I'm not sure, if it was clearly set. Part A should have max degree set to 2<2,3,4> and for B is 2*A. That's the number for max vertexes coming from each node. Script should draws max of these possible graphs.